# Maximize the next split window after closing one

Tags: vim

If I have multiple split windows opened in Vim and I close the current one. Vim will automatically make the rest of the split windows equal-sized. And then I have to manually maximize the one that is currently focused. What can I do to auto-maximize the next focused window after I close the current one, hopefully in one key stroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on how you're closing the window, but you could easily map a window closing and full screening mapp like this;

`map <C-t> <c-w>q<c-w>_`